# Adding a Saiku Plugin - Saiku Chart Plus

Tags: data-visualization, saiku

I'm trying to run Saiku with a plugin, Saiku Chart Plus (http://it4biz.github.io/SaikuChartPlus/) without Pentaho BI. I've followed the instructions on the download page for the advanced installation, editing the saiku/ui/index.html file and adding the following code:

```
    <!--search for this and put the files under this-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/saiku/plugins/Chart/plugin.js" defer></script>

    <!--start js SaikuChartPlus-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/saiku/plugins/SaikuChartPlus/plugin.js" defer>        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
 google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['geochart','geomap']});
    </script>
    <!--end js SaikuChartPlus-->
```

Then, I am supposed to download the project and extract the folder on saiku/ui/js/saiku/plugins/ . When I go to the file it indicates, there is already a file folder for Saiku Chart Plus, however, when I run saiku, it does not have the plugin functionality. What extra step am I missing?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this issue https://github.com/it4biz/SaikuChartPlus/issues/3

?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The project that you are extracting is a self working package. This is for Pentaho USE. In fact, to use High CHart PLus on Saiku only, you have to go deep inside (saikuchartsplus-plugin-2.4-RC1.zip\saikuchartsplus-plugin-2.4-RC1\saiku\ui\js\saiku\plugins\SaikuChartPlus). Once here CUt/paste it to the plugins direccotry in SAIKU 2.x ( saiku server 2.6\saikuchartsplus-plugin-2.4-RC1\saiku\ui\js\saiku\plugins\SaikuChartPlus).